# Any Java library to get call graph for a whole Java program and AST for each single file?

Tags: eclipse, translation, static-analysis

I am trying to do some style-check/translation work for Java programs.

First I would like a library (preferably in Java) so I can use it in my program. 
Second I expect it can do the following:

- scan a whole program (multiple source files)
- provide APIs to access AST for single files
- provide APIs to access call graph, e.g. know all references of a variable, all callers of a method, etc.

In limited time, I briefly examined several tools, such as eclipse, pmd, antlr, soot:

- **PMD and ANTLR:** lexers/parsers, they are able to get ASTs, but no call graphs since they do not process multiple files
- **Eclipse:** it seems they provide APIs but only usable within its plugin framework, or binded with its RCP (does not serve as a common use library used in a stand-alone program)
- **Soot:** seems very close to my requirements. I am reading documents about it.

Correct me if I have misunderstanding for the above.

Comment: It is probably easy enough to make ANTLR parse multiple Java files; that's not the cause of "no call graph".  The real problem is that you have to know what the meanings of each symbol use is, you have to compute a points-to analysis, and then you have to compute a call graph.   Mere parsers are far away from providing a solution.

Comment: Yes, you can use eclipse JDT AST and JDT Search to figure out the call graphs (that's how they do it) but you are correct, it will only run within the OSGi framework with the code in eclipse projects in the workspace (it needs to know project dependencies and the  classpath in order to figure stuff out).

Comment: @PaulWebster Thanks for confirming this. If proper APIs are provided, it is not a big deal to create a temporary workspace, create project with my source code directory and then use JDT to get AST and call graph. But eclipse seems to only provide those APIs to those programs (such as plugins) within its framework. I cannot freely use them in elsewhere. Soot seems to suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is should be possible to use Eclipse Java compiler and its data structures as a library without RCP, etc. You may want to explore how eclipsec.exe handles this feat. That's the Eclipse equivalent to javac.exe for cases where a command-line compilation is desired.

Comment: I think eclipsec.exe is another launcher executable, just linked with the windows console libraries so that you can use it with -consoleLog in a cmd.exe window.